# stop the sprite going off the tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, edges

How can I stop the player character going off the edges of the screen and stop at the boundaries?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 500
window = Tk()
window.title('Colour Shooter')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')
c.pack()

ship_id = c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill='white')
MID_X = (WIDTH/2)-25
c.move(ship_id, MID_X, HEIGHT-50)
left_bound= c.create_line(0, 0, 800, 0,)
right_bound= c.create_line(500, 0, 500, 500,)

SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)


from math import sqrt
def collision_bound():
    dist_left = left_bound.x + ship_id.x 
    if dist_left < 0:
        c.move(ship_id, 50, HEIGHT-50)
    dist_right = right_bound.x - ship_id.x
    if dist_right > WIDTH:
        c.move(ship_id, WIDTH - 50, HEIGHT-50)
```

I'm very new to python and the book I have failed to teach me how to solve this problem. so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `c.coords(ship_id)` to get the position of the ship, then you can check if they are allowed to move.

Try replacing

```
if event.keysym == 'Left':
    c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
elif event.keysym == 'Right':
    c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
```

With

```
shipPosition = c.coords(ship_id)
if event.keysym == 'Left' and shipPostion[0] > c.coords(left_bound)[0]:
    c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
elif event.keysym == 'Right' and shipPosition[0] < c.coords(right_bound)[0]:
    c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
```

Which should only allow the player to move left if their position is greater than the x position of the left bound, and only allow the player to move right if their position is less than the x position of the right bound.

However, since the position of the ship is determined by the left side, you'll probably want to change it to

```
elif event.keysym == 'Right' and shipPosition[0] < c.coords(right_bound)[0] - 50:
    c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
```

Where 50 is the size of the ship.